# Wrong timezone UTC in laravel 5.0?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, timezone, timestamp

I set `'timezone' => 'UTC',` in `config/app.php`.

And use this web: [UTC online](http://www.worldtimeserver.com/current_time_in_UTC.aspx) to view current time.

Then I create a row in database, with time: [image]

But the row be create in my database, value of column `created_at` and `updated_at` (timestamp) are : `2016-01-11 06:25:11` (wrong seconds).

Any helps. Thanks!

Comment: What is your current timezone

Comment: http://www.worldtimeserver.com/current_time_in_UTC.aspx. I see UTC online in here

Answer (score 0):

In your `config/app.php`

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Timezone
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the default timezone for your application, which
| will be used by the PHP date and date-time functions. We have gone
| ahead and set this to a sensible default for you out of the box.
|
*/

'timezone' => 'UTC',
```

**Instead of UTC** you can simply substitute any of the PHP supported timezones. For example, a few of the apps I've worked on have `Australia/Sydney` to keep all the times localised here, even through daylight savings.

> **If you really wanted you could go ahead and place a call to `date_default_timezone_set()` somewhere in your app boot, but this is build cleanly into Laravel.**